# how to integrate web cam in aspx page using c#?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, silverlight

My requirement is to integrate a web camera in aspx page and i need to capure a picture for the customers and insert in the database. I have tried with flash player,Aforge dll and silverlight.  Can anyone suggest me  an easy way to integrate web camera  in aspx page. I have been trying this for a long time now.

Comment: There is no easy way integrating hardware devices with browser applications. In the past I have integrated several hardware devices using ActiveX. But that is now outdated and IE specific. Eventhough Html5 has some support, for now we have to rely on Flash, Silver based apps only. check this: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/528929/Capture-images-using-web-camera-in-ASP-NET and this: http://www.kirupa.com/html5/accessing_your_webcam_in_html5.htm

Answer (score 0):

DirectShow.Net is really your best option to achieve this functionality. C# and the .Net framework do not provide really any support or API's for webcam access.

http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/about.html

Comment: Thank you so much for such a quivk response....is the link u gave a solution...Can u suggest me some solution..I would be grateful to you..I really need to get this done..

Comment: Thanx..I will try with this link

Comment: It can be used as a solution to your problem :)

Comment: Hi Jason..could u please provide me a source code for this.I would be thankful to you

Comment: okaty..could u please tell me how do i do that..m actually new to stack overflow

Comment: how do I choose as selected answer please tell me

Answer (score 0):

You can you silverlight to detect any USB camera attached your system. 
In silverlight there are predefined classes for detecting removable devices attached to the system if you want i can give you the working code .. and steps to do this functionality

Comment: Hi rajendra..I have tried with silverlight I can capture the picture.But how will I integrate that in my aspx page.I have a registration page which is on aspx i need to capture the pic on this page and insert into database..my doubt is if I use silverlight page i get a seperate file for silverlight..how will i integrate the web cam in the aspx page which is my registration page..could u please help me out

Answer (score 0):

U need to use Model PopUp Extender of asp and for that model popup set the source to the Silverlight Page which capture the image and u will need to write the web service which will take the captured image and convert it to the byte array and then it store that Image in the DB these are the steps u will need to do. If u want i can help u with all kind of source code help u will need just try it and tell me if u are ok with this..